# How to print the gitinfo2 watermark vertically on the margin?

Tags: margins, gitinfo

I know that I can insert a watermark containing information about the git revision into my document using the [`gitinfo2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2?lang=de) package like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[mark]{gitinfo2}
%You need to install gitinfo2 as described in the manual before compiling this

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I modify this that the git watermark occurs vertically on the left or on the right margin (similar to the watermark of [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/) papers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gitinfo2}% Don't pass mark option here
%You need to install gitinfo2 as described in the manual before compiling this

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \kern1cm
      \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}
        {\rotatebox{90}{\gitMarkFormat\gitMarkPref{} \textbullet{} \gitMark}}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

(Image is ready but upload failed due to some unspecified `error at imgur`; ok it works 10 hours later)

[image]

And with some customizing of `\gitMarkFormat` (in particular `\small` was not quite adapted to a vertical mark in left margin).

[image]

This is with

```
\renewcommand{\gitMarkFormat}{\color{blue}\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
```

added to preamble.

Comment: you may prefer LaTeX markup `\hspace{1cm}%` in place of `\kern 1cm`. Actually that's what I had in source code for blue example but I did not copy paster it to answer.